# Array Difference Helpers on Laravel 9

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-9, array-difference

I want to get the difference between the two arrays in my controller. If I use `array_diff()` function, it gives me an error `array_diff(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, Illuminate\Support\Collection given`.

```
$newListOfArray = array_diff($newArrayTags, $oldArrayTags);
```

Both arrays are definitely arrays.

My `$oldArrayTags` array.

```
#items: array:2 [▼
   0 => "egg"
   1 => "beef"
]
```

My `$newArrayTags` array.

```
#items: array:4 [▼
   0 => "egg"
   1 => "beef"
   2 => "chicken"
   3 => "sausage"
]
```

When I checked on [Laravel 9 Array Helpers Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#arrays-and-objects-method-list), I couldn't find any array helpers that will provide the difference.

Questions:

1. Why am I getting an error if I use `array_diff` though it was an array?
2. What is the array helper in Laravel 9 that I can use to get the difference between two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like a collection, not array
you can use collection diff method https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-diff

`$newArrayTags->diff($oldArrayTags)`

or using array_diff if you prefer:

`$newListOfArray = array_diff($newArrayTags->toArray(), $oldArrayTags->toArray());`

Comment: OMG! I was on the wrong page. It did solve my issue. Thanks, @Chinh Nguyen. I will mark this as the Answer in 5mins.. Cheers!